# Tapestry 5 multiple file upload

Tags: file-upload, tapestry

From what I've seen on the official Tapestry site, They're only talking about one file about uploading.
I have a project with Tapestry 5 and I need to upload multiple files (an amount not fixed), How can I do multiple files uploading with Tapestry 5 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Tawus](https://github.com/tawus/tawus/tree/master/tawus-ajaxupload) Tapestry module. It wraps [FileUploader](http://fineuploader.com/). Add it to your classpath and user the [`AjaxUpload`](https://github.com/tawus/tawus/blob/master/tawus-ajaxupload/src/main/java/com/googlecode/tawus/ajaxupload/components/AjaxUpload.java) component

Comment: That component is not a solution for me because is based on commercial pay license library.

Answer (score 0):

How about use Dropzone.js with Tapestry: [Accessing uploaded file in Apache Tapestry page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015378/accessing-uploaded-file-in-apache-tapestry-page/39986560#39986560) ...See the solution I posted; which works for me...All you need to do is drop multiple files into the dropzone form and there is one request created per file to upload